# count the occurrences of alphabet of string in python

Tags: python, count

String containing both upper and lower case alphabets.

We need to count the number of occurrences of each alphabet(case insensitive) and display the same.

Below is the program,but does not led to desired output

output should be-
2A 3B 2C 1G

my output is -
A 2
B 3
A 2
B 3
C 2
B 3
G 1
C 2

```
String="ABaBCbGc"
String1=String.upper()
for i in String1:
    print(i,String1.count(i))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print will separate the args with a space. Concatenate them with `+`. `count()` is an int so it needs to be converted to a string.

```
String="ABaBCbGc"
counts = {}
String1=String.upper()
for i in String1:
    counts[i] = String1.count(i)

for k in counts.keys():
    print(str(counts[k]) + k)

2A
3B
2C
1G
```

Comment: it does not led to the desired output.I want distinct alphabets

Answer (score 5):

Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

String = "ABaBCbGc"

counts = Counter(String.lower())

print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'a': 2, 'g': 1})
```

If you prefer upper case, just change `str.lower` to `str.upper`. Or use a dictionary to keep track of the counts:

```
string = "ABaBCbGc"
counts = {}
for c in string.upper():
    counts[c] = counts.get(c, 0) + 1

print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
{'C': 2, 'B': 3, 'A': 2, 'G': 1}
```

Comment: is there any other method?

Comment: @TanyaChaudhary added another method, using a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Create the sorted input string as the values and the sorted keys of this string as the keys. Iterate the keys and count their occurrences in the values.

```
data = "ABaBCbGc".upper()
values = ''.join(sorted(data))
keys = sorted(''.join(set(data)))
for key in keys:
    print(str(values.count(key))+key)
```

Output:

```
2A
3B
2C
1G
```